# Can "some feature" be correct?

Tags: determiners

> *His right hand, which he often raised to point at **some feature** or
>   other, was knotted and twisted, and when I gazed at it, set against
>   Harvard’s antediluvian steeples and columns, it seemed to me the claw
>   of some mythical creature.*

Is this text which says "**some feature**" (in singular) correct or it should be **some feature**s (in plural)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the singular "feature" is correct.

"Some" here is not used to mean "a few". [Definition four from Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/some) reads:

> used to mean a person or thing, when you do not know or say exactly which
>
> - There must be some reason for her behaviour.
> - Can you give me some idea of the cost?

So, in this case, the specific feature is undefined but it is singular - note both "reason" and "idea" in the example sentences are singular. I'm not sure the context of what's being pointed out but an alternate phrasing of this could be more specific:

> [...] he often raised to point at a building or statue [...]

The thing that's being pointed at is singular, so "feature" is singular.

Answer (score 2):

In this context it should be "some feature" (in singular). It isn't talking about plural but it simply means a **not known** (or it doesn't matters to mention) feature.

From [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-russian/some_1): 
Some: 
UNKNOWN NAME

> used to refer to someone or something when you do not know the name of
>   it or exact details about it
>
> - Some girl phoned for you, but she didn't leave a message.

In a [different Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some): 
Some:

> used to refer to a particular person or thing without stating exactly
>   which one:
>
> - Some lucky person will win more than $1,000,000 in the competition.
> - Some idiot's locked the door!
> - There must be some way you can relieve the pain.